# Redux select() api returns intialstate

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my initial state for the messagesReducer.

```
const initialState = {
  messages: [],
  messageLeftPanel: {},
  messageFunnel: 'All',
  messageAsSender: '',
  selectedMessagePanelItem: '',
  fcmToken: {}
};
```

I used select API from the redux to access the state variable from the store since useSelector cannot be used outside the functional component.

```
export const SelectFcmToken = state => state.MessagesReducer
const Token = yield select (SelectFcmToken);
```

Even though I could see that the state has been updated in the redux toolkit extension, the select API returns the initial state that I have mentioned in the above code snippet.
I cannot access the updated state value.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `store.getState()` to get your state if your function is outside of a component.
- If your function is a generator fn / saga you can use `createSelectors` from reselect npm.

Comment: I have tried using store.getState() to access the state but still I was able to get only the initial state, not the updated state.